# Ultrastable capacitor wrt temperature

Tags: capacitor

It seems the best temperature stability I can get with conventional capacitors in the 330pF range are COG/NPO ceramics at 30ppm.

Are there any better technologies, or techniques I can use to compensate for capacitor drift?

Comment: I smell some xy problem here: why would you even want/need to? The places where you need very precise cap values should be pretty rare

Comment: Position detecting using inductive sensing to sub-micron. The LC of the coil has to be as temperature independent as possible. I can compensate mechanically with dimension changes in the coil, but not the capacitor

Comment: COG/NPO will give me a temperature stability over 10 degC of around 1:100,000 which is not good enough

Comment: @DirkBruere Inductive sensing to sub-micron? Can you elaborate based on which method? Is this a LVDT sensor, or just an inductive proximity sensor? Think you want impossible.

Comment: There may be a way around this but you need to explain more about the application.

Comment: @Andyaka I am thinking of using the TI LDC1612 inductive sensor to measure the position of a "thing" through about 5mm-10mm of glass

http://www.ti.com/product/LDC1612

Comment: Maybe you could keep the capacitors raised at (say) 50degC using a resistor and temperature sensor?

Comment: @Andyaka: There's precedent for that; an "oven" design is commonly used to avoid temperature-dependent frequency changes in crystal oscillators.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oven.

Comment: @NateEldredge of course there is a precedent for it. They've been in use for this sort of thing since Queen Vic was on the throne!

Comment: Vacuum capacitor? No physical dielectric means do discernible drift...

Answer (score 8):

Andeen Hagerling make ultra-stable capacitance standards up to about 100pF, part number AH11A.  They are stable to 0.001ppm/C, and also have low drift (0.1ppm/yr), high Q, and low voltage dependence.  They are probably too expensive for your application though.  They achieve this kind of stability with fused silica capacitors in a temperature controlled oven.

If you want a precision distance measurement cheaper than a laser system, you might consider a capacitance sensor. But you're going to have a rough time beating the price and performance of the laser system.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to deal with this sort of problem is to use a differential measurement method so the capacitance(s) cancel(s) out to first order.

As an alternative, at 30pF you might be able to make your own air dielectric capacitor using (say) Invar that would be relatively stable, but the cost would be high (and you might get too much humidity sensitivity unless you sealed it with something like dry argon inside. 330pF is probably too much to make easily, but maybe you could just increase the frequency.

Getting inductive measurements at relatively low frequency is quite tough anyway because the skin depth is not zero for a conventional conductor (it's not quite zero for a superconductor either, but much closer).

Comment: The alternative is a COTS laser system at around $2000

Comment: Not quite that cheap I think but there are some very nice vibrometry measurement systems using modulated ultrastable lasers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to achieve the impossible. In general in electronics we accept that the component values vary over temperature and design for it. Trying to minimize the drift over temperature is a good idea but there will be a wall you will hit at some point.

To break this wall and increase accuracy the solution I can think of is to  compensate for the temperature induced error for the measured value. So you measure the temperature as well, then using a table with the error over temperature, correct the measured value.

You could also try and compensate the temperature coefficient with a different type of capacitor having a reversed temperature coefficient in parallel with your original capacitor. However I doubt if these exist and this might also be not very predictable.

Comment: Yes. I was however hoping that someone might know of some clever way of getting around this, similar to the way that the expansion of the coils with temperature can be compensated. For example, a disc whose area expands to match the thermal expansion of the distance between the separate layers

Comment: You can also control the temperature. That's what's done when you need stable oscillators and voltage references.

Comment: What pipe says: in electronics a crystal oscillator is sometimes run at a constant (elevated) temperature, for example at 60 degrees C. A simple power resistor (thermally coupled to the crystal and a temperature sensor) and a temperature control loop regulate the temperature.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I can do that. I have already built a unit that can hold  a small metal enclosure within 15 mK of a set temperature. However, not sure whether I can apply this in practice to the sensor due to positioning requirements. Time for experiments...

Comment: I agree with pipe. Temperature controlled voltage references are common off-the-shelf- products now, and relatively 'cheap'. A TLZ1000 voltage reference is $30 to $50, but it provides a 6.99999999volt ref with as low as 10ppb drift. Even a DIY oven for a tiny NPO capacitor would make it as stable as practical. Another option is a voltage controlled capacitor in parallel, but some way to measure drift would have to be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your temperature range is, but over the range of -40C to 85C ambient your total drift would be...
330pF * 30ppm/C * 65C = 0.64pF.

0.64pF is pretty small, you are likely to have more capacitance error than that due to just a few inches of cabling or PCB traces.  Also the change in capacitance in the windings of your inductor coil vs. temperature are likely to be larger than that.  Inductors can easily have several 10s of pF of inter-winding capacitance.

So overall, to get the accuracy you desire, you need to know more than just the capacitance of one component vs. temperature, you need to know the whole system (PCB cables and all) vs temperature.

I would use an ordinary NP0 capacitor, and put a temperature sensor near it on your circuit card then at the time of manufacture you can put the device in a temperature chamber and measure the total system capacitance at several temperatures, by reversing your distance calculation, and store it in a look-up table in your device.  You probably don't need to measure too many temperature points since you can probably interpolate with reasonable accuracy.

Then when you are operating in your target environment you can then look up the correct capacitance based on your temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0):

I will post this as an answer, although it is only a possibility. Using 4 layer 1mm FR4 I can get 340pF by creating my own disc capacitor of radius 18mm.

I still need to do thermal expansion calculations. I suspect it is not going to be better than COG/NPO

Comment: I think FR4 will be about 70ppm/C. If you're looking to make your own, you'd probably be best off metallising both sides of a thin piece of low thermal expansion glass (or fused silica). Your friendly local semiconductor fab can probably do that for you pretty cheaply.

Comment: The coefficients of thermal expansion for most FR-4 materials are in the range of 14-18 ppm (X, Y) and 35 (Z) below Tg - I would not expect your application to exceed Tg.

Comment: Dupont Pyralux AP (flexible) = 45ppm, plus I assume it's an isotropic material

Comment: https://www.multi-circuit-boards.eu/en/pcb-design-aid/pcb-materials.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to invent another method to make these measurements. The precision level you request is not realistic.

You can consider, for example, modulation of the useful component of your signal. I suggest to read a description of a famous experiment to measure the effect of gravitation on photon frequency. They used mechanical modulation of the useful signal.